# javascript, jquery setInetval append

Tags: javascript, jquery, функции, setinterval, append

Есть такой код:

```js
<div id='chatbox-list'></div>
<script>
function Test() {
        
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: '/blabla'
            }).done(function (data) {
                if (data.length > 0) {
                     $('#chatbox-list').append(data);
                }
            });
                        
        }
        
setInterval(Test, 2000);
</script>
```

data это:

```js
<div id='test'> </div>
Какой-то HTML код

<script>
function Name(){
   $.ajax()
.....
   $('#test').append('blabla');
.....
}

setInterval(Name,1000);
</script>
```

Внимание вопрос знатокам:)

После добавления HTML и Javascript в , как сделать так, чтобы выполнялся setInterval(Name,1000) и соответственно function Name() ?
Может есть какое-то другое решение, которое позволит выполнять через определенный промежуток времени динамически добавляемую функцию?

Comment: Стоп... а ничего, что у вас раз в 2 секунды начнет добавляться новый интервал и через пару минут их будет сотни? Может в data нужен setTimeout ?

Comment: Вместо интервалов вызовите name() сразу, так вы сделаете первую отправку ajax, потом при приходе ответа (в done у вас) сделайте таймер (не интервал) в котором новый вызов name(). Так вы избавитесь от накопления запросов-без-ответов и от прихода второго ответа раньше первого (сервер не обязан отвечать второй ответ раньше первого, он может выполнять первй долго, а второй моментально).

Comment: Я пишу чат переписку между пользователями. Каждые 2 сек. будет проверяться есть ли новые запросы на переписку. Если есть, то подгружается кусок HTML с формой и JS для отправки/получения новых сообщений. Вообщем решил сделать загрузку JS на eval() и отдельно HTML через append. В JS тоже должен быть свой setInteval который проверяет есть ли новые сообщения.

Comment: Спасибо за идею о том, что не накапливать запрос-ответ!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вставленный в виде строки скрипт не будет работать. Есть два варианта его обработать:

1. [eval()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)
2. `createElement("script")`

```js
let data = 'name(); function name() { console.log("Name!!!"); }';

eval(data);

/***/

let script = document.createElement('script');
script.innerHTML = data;
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Но так добавлять скрипты, тем более раз в 2 секунды - плохая идея, как минимум потому что может возникнуть конфликт имен переменных.

И еще, что будет, если ответы начнут задерживаться, а запросы так и будут отправляться раз в 2 секунды? Поэтому можно отправлять следующий запрос только после получения предыдущего, зациклив их через setTimeout.

А вместо вставки целого скрипта, можно завернуть data в JSON, который будет хранить все необходимые данные для обработки, около того:

```
/*  data = {
 *    "html": "<div>bubu...</div>",
 *    "scriptData": {
 *      "text": "example.com",
 *      "timeout": 1000,
        "appendTo": "#test"
 *    }
 *  }
 */

let STOP_AJAX = false;

ajaxLoop();

function ajaxLoop() {
  $.ajax({
    // ляляля
  }).done(function (data) {
    handleAjaxData(data);

    if ( STOP_AJAX ) return;
    // Чтобы можно было остановить запросы в случае чего.

    setTimeout(ajaxLoop, 2000); // Функция вызывает саму себя
  });
}

function handleAjaxData(data) {
  if( !data.length ) return;

  data = JSON.parse(data);

  if( data.html ) $('#chatbox-list').append(data.html);

  if( data.scriptData ) {
    // вместо вашей функции Name
    let elem = data.scriptData.appendTo;
    let text = data.scriptData.text;
    let tick = data.scriptData.timeOut;

    setTimeout(function(){
      $(elem).append(text);

      // Или например, еще один запрос, если по другому никак.
    }, tick);
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Я пишу чат переписку между пользователями. Каждые 2 сек. будет проверяться есть ли новые запросы на переписку. Если есть, то подгружается кусок HTML с формой  и JS для отправки/получения новых сообщений. Вообщем решил сделать загрузку JS на eval() и отдельно HTML через append.  В JS тоже должен быть свой setInteval который проверяет есть ли новые сообщения.Протестил вроде работает.

Comment: @plavv тогда можно еще завести какую-нибудь внешнюю переменную, чтобы после получения запроса, стереть предыдущий интервал... `let interval = null;` - - прилетел ответ -- `.done( clearInterval(interval); eval(data); )` — при этом интервал из дата будет такой `interval = setInterval(ляляля)` чтобы запомнить номер текущего интервала для следующего удаления.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понял, но потести это:

```html
<script>
(()=>{
    const Name=()=>{
        // $.ajax();
        $('#test').append('blabla');
    };
    setInterval(Name, 1000);
})();
</script>
```